# Joining 2 Tables Gives Null Result

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to combine these two tables.

Sales Table

[image]

Expense Table

[image]

Here is my code to combine them:

```
SELECT sl.month, sl.sumnet, ex.sumexp, (sl.sumnet-ex.sumexp) AS profit
FROM
    (SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y') AS date_id, 
            DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') AS month, 
            YEAR(date) AS year, SUM(net_sales) AS sumnet 
    FROM sales 
    GROUP BY month) sl
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y') AS date_id, 
                DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') AS month, 
                YEAR(date) AS year, SUM(total) as sumexp 
        FROM expense 
        GROUP BY month) ex 
    ON sl.date_id = ex.date_id 
WHERE sl.year = '2021'
ORDER BY sl.date_id ASC
```

I wanted to show results for the year 2021 only but the November shows `NULL` for the `sumexp` and `profit` columns (see below). How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: are you sure ex table.sumexp  is not null when you execute it ? and it becomes null while using it as subquery ?

Comment: Yes. As you can see on the expense table above, the Nov 2021 row shows 20.500 result

Comment: can you delete this clouse and try ? : WHERE sl.year = '2021'

Comment: still shows null value

Comment: can you provide sql fiddle so we can try on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY

```
SELECT sl.month, sl.sumnet, ex.sumexp, (sl.sumnet-ex.sumexp) AS profit
FROM
    (SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y') AS date_id, 
            DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') AS month, 
            YEAR(date) AS year, SUM(net_sales) AS sumnet 
    FROM sales 
    WHERE year='2021'
    GROUP BY month) sl
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y') AS date_id, 
                DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') AS month, 
                YEAR(date) AS year, SUM(total) as sumexp 
        FROM expense 
        WHERE year='2021'
        GROUP BY month) ex 
    ON sl.date_id = ex.date_id 
ORDER BY sl.date_id ASC
```

you have filtered the year only for one table so the other one is showing null with multiple value.

Comment: This one worked, thanks for pointing it out! I haven't thought of that.

Comment: Happy to help :) please vote up if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Posible answer, you must take care of `nulls`

```
select
 s.date_id,
 s.`month` ,
 s.`year` ,
 sum(s.sumnet),
 sum(distinct coalesce(e.sumexp,0)),
 sum(s.sumnet) - sum(distinct coalesce(e.sumexp,0)) 
from sales as s
left join expanse as e on s.date_id = e.date_id and s.`month` = e.`month` and s.`year` = e.`year`
group by date_id, `month` , `year`;
```

And filter by your desire.